# нужно заменить ключ в словаре так, чтобы сохранить порядок Python

Tags: python, dict

запарсил погоду на неделю и дни к которым эта температура относится, проблема в том что 3 слова не с тем окончанием что мне нужно, а именно - 'среда', 'пятница', 'суббота'. Нужно чтобы у этих ключей было окончание 'среду', 'пятницу', 'субботу'. вот код:

```
def weather(soup):
    weather = soup.find_all('div', class_='day-temperature')
    days = soup.find_all('div', class_='day-week')
    only_days = [d.text.lower() for d in days]
    only_int = [w.text for w in weather]
    w_week = {}
    for i in range(len(only_days)):
        w_week.update({only_days[i]: only_int[i]})
    
   print(w_week) #{'суббота': '+26°', 'воскресенье': '+26°', 'понедельник': '+28°', 'вторник': '+22°', 'среда': '+23°', 'четверг': '+21°', 'пятница': '+21°'}
```

данные в словаре динамические и меняются в зависимости от изменений на странице откуда производится парсинг, поэтому при замене ИМЕННО ЭТИХ СЛОВ они должны оказаться на том же месте где и были в словаре. Помогите пожалуйста, а то я уже буксую

Comment: на том же месте в словаре это как ? словарь - неупорядоченная структура данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил так. Возможно не самый оптимальный вариант.
Поясню: Я запускаю цикл с копией словаря и на каждой итерации беру ключ и значение из словаря. Дальше проверяю, если ключ (в данном случае день недели) находится в списке для изменения, я вырезаю значение, сохранив его в буфер. Далее я просто создаю ещё один ключ в словаре с уже изменённым окончанием. Для остальных ключей, которые не нужно исправлять, просто повторяю операцию без изменения окончания (для того чтобы элементы остались на своих местах).

```
w_week = {'суббота': '+26°', 'воскресенье': '+26°', 'понедельник': '+28°', 'вторник': '+22°', 'среда': '+23°', 'четверг': '+21°', 'пятница': '+21°'}

for key, value in w_week.copy().items():
    bufer = w_week.pop(key)
    if key in ["среда", "пятница", "суббота"]:
        w_week[key[:-1]+"у"] = bufer
    else:
        w_week[key] = bufer
print(w_week)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: спасибо, вы мой спаситель <3

Comment: Я думал об этом варианте:-), но сложность кода выше, чем при прямой замене, а элементов всего три на замену. Потому и остановился на прямой перезаписи с удалением старой.

Answer (score 0):

Формулировка в вопросе сложновата для понимания, но если вы хотите заменить названия ключей, при этом, чтобы к новым ключам были привязаны старые значения, то можно "в лоб" так действовать (рабочий пример для демонстрации, модифицируйте свой код по этой логике - взяв две строки с комментариями и распространив на два других дня):

```
w_week = {}
w_week['среду'] = 5
print (w_week)
# Создаём новую запись, беря значение из старой
w_week['среда'] = w_week['среду']
# Удаляем старую запись
del w_week['среду']
print (w_week)
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: К сожалению, после этого порядок перечисления элементов списка при использовании print() измениться. Я тоже сначала пошел этим путем, но увы.

Comment: @passant, спасибо, так вот оно о чем про "порядок"! Я бы вообще не привязывался на месте автора к порядку записей в словаре для вывода, а выводил по порядку ключей, перечисленных в отдельном списке, напрмер. Для неупорядоченной структуры такая привязка может "упасть" при любом изменении.

Comment: @Сергей с версии 3.7 `dict` гарантирует, что при итерации элементы выдаются в том же порядке, что и заносились. Только вот надолго ли это изменение, вот в чём вопрос )

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков, я это знаю, но посмотрите  на проблему, уже возникшую у автора. Я полагаю хорошим, что это изменение расширяет возможности языка, но идеологически к словарю оно всё равно не очень подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще не исправлять уже полученный словарь, а заменять ключи при его создании. Ну и для простоты сделал проверку не по списку дней недели, которые нужно менять, а по окончанию

```
w_week = dict(zip(map((lambda x: x if not x.endswith('а') else x[:-1]+'у'), only_days), only_int))
```